# How to skip an option tag in a select element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

So I do have this function named `getValue` that retrieves `option value` by using `variable` that has string on it. My questions is how can I skip the `option` with a value of `'0'`, and just scan or find the other remaining `options`. Some of you may ask, why not just change the text `'Dog'`?. In my main code `var myText` is dynamic, meaning it can changed from a click, for example a table row.

**code:**

```js
function getValue() {
  var myText = "Dog"
  $("#animals option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() == myText;
  }).val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animals">
  <option value='0'>Dog
    <option>
      <option value='1'>Dog
        <option>
          <option value='2'>Cat
            <option>
</select>
```

Comment: As you can see when I added your code to a Stack Snippet and clicked Tidy, the HTML code uses `<option>` like `</option>`. This should be causing the browser to display blank options...

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your `filter()` to also check the `value`:

Pure JS example, since [you might not need jquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/):

```js
function getValue(myText = "Dog") {
    const options = [ ...document.querySelectorAll("#animals option") ];
    return options.filter((e) => {
        return e.value !== '0' && e.innerHTML === myText;
    });
}

const res = getValue();
console.log(res);
```

```html
<select id = "animals">
  <option value = '0'>Dog<option>
  <option value = '1'>Dog<option>
  <option value = '2'>Cat<option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd stick with jQuery and use its additional [`:contains()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find the text match, along with [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to limit the `value` match.

Note that using `:contains()` means it will match both "Dog" and "Weiner Dog" if that option was present and would match the first one.

```js
function getValue() {
  var myText = "Dog"
  return $("#animals option:contains('" + myText + "'):not([value='0'])").val();
}
console.log(getValue());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animals">
  <option value='0'>Dog</option>
  <option value='1'>Dog</option>
  <option value='2'>Cat</option>
</select>
```